# Find the "nextes" div having a specific class

Tags: jquery

Hi i want to select the next div in the dom having a specific class.

with this :

```
<div class="comW"></div>
.....
Some divs
.....
<div class="comWF"></div>
```

i want to select the div.comWF after the comW div but it may have some other div before comWF and after comW

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: i dont know how to do that without checking the class of each next div after comW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nextAll` and `:first` selector:

```
$('.comW').nextAll('.comWF:first')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zdZmn/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `jQuery.nextAll()` [specs here](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
 $('.comW').nextAll('.comWF');
```

If you have many `.comWF` divs you can also use

```
 $('.comW').nextAll('.comWF:first-child');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. long time using jQuery gets me rusty :P. The solution I find is to put a parent div and iterate searching for the class requiered

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="comW"></div>
  <div class="comWF"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var parent = document.getElementsById('parent').children,
    e, i, j;

// or get the parent by classname
// document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0].children,

for (i = 0, j = parent.length; i < j; i += 1) {
    e = parent[i];
    if ('comWF' === e.className) {
        // ... action
        break;
    }
}
```